# Some form fields not receiving a value after making an AJAX request

Tags: html, jquery, ajax

I want to edit a form but some of the values are not being filled after clicking on the edit button. I have shared the AJAX response and jQuery code. Can anyone help me resolve this problem?

[image]

Response:

```js
[
  {
    "category": "2",
    "item_name": "21",
    "amount": "10000",
    "total_tax": "1800",
    "variation": "2",
    "rate": "10",
    "f_length": "1000",
    "nop": "5"
  }, {
    "category": "1",
    "item_name": "23",
    "amount": "40000",
    "total_tax": "7200",
    "variation": "2",
    "rate": "20",
    "f_length": "2000",
    "nop": "6"
  }
], 
"po_notes_details": [
  { "note_desc": "a" },
  { "note_desc": "a" },
```

```js
$(document).on("click", ".edit_record", function() {
  var edit_id = $(this).data('purchase_id');

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'ajax_task.php',
    data: {
      edit_id: edit_id,
      purchase_edit: 'purchase_edit'
    },
    success: function(data) {
      var response = JSON.parse(data);
      $('#category').val(response.category);
      $('#item_name').val(response.item_name);
      $('#variation').val(response.variation);
      $('#rate').val(response.rate);
      $('#f_length').val(response.f_length);
      $('#terms_condition').val(response.terms_condition);
      $('#payment_terms').val(response.payment_terms);
      $('#purchase_name').val(response.purchase_name);
      $('#purchase_type').val(response.purchase_type);
      $('#purchase_data_iud').val(response.purchase_id);
      $('#purchase_date').val(response.purchase_date);
      $('#po_no').val(response.po_number);
      $('#po_cat').val(response.po_cat);
      $('#po_type').val(response.po_type);
      $('#effective_start_date').val(response.effective_start_date);
      $('#effective_end_date').val(response.effective_end_date);
      $('#mode_of_despatch').val(response.mode_of_despatch);
      $('#transportation_charges').val(response.transportation_charges);
      $('#insurance_charges').val(response.insurance_charges);
      $('#packing_charges').val(response.packing_charges);
      $('#project_lead_time').val(response.project_lead_time);
      $('#state').val(response.state);
      $('#vendor_quote_no').val(response.vendor_quote_no);
      $('#vendor_quote_date').val(response.vendor_quote_date);
      $('#installation_services_charges').val(response.install_and_service_charges);
      $('#other_charges').val(response.item_cost_oth_charges);
      $('#grand_total').val(response.grand_total);
      $('#grand_total_tax').val(response.grand_total_tax);
      $('#total_amount').val(response.total_amount);
      $('#purchase_data_iud').val(response.purchase_id);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: From what I can see it looks like one of those that does not work is `response.f_length)` correct?. Try with `response.po_item_details[0].f_length)` since `f_length` is in an array from `po_item_details`

Comment: I've edited your question. Please use this format in future - ie. the title is a short description of the problem and the description of the issue is in the question itself. Also, please do not use images of code - they are useless and waste your time creating them. Just copy/paste code in to the question. Lastly, don't use `alert()` for debugging. Use `console.log()` or `console.dir()`

Comment: thanks i am getting f-length but category and item_name is not working with this

Comment: @Ginie It would be more helpful if you could edit the question and add the actual json response and html. That way we can test what the problem is

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen  this  is my jason format[{"category":"2","item_name":"21","amount":"10000","total_tax":"1800","variation":"2","rate":"10","f_length":"1000","nop":"5"},{"category":"1","item_name":"23","amount":"40000","total_tax":"7200","variation":"2","rate":"20","f_length":"2000","nop":"6"}],"po_notes_details":[{"note_desc":"a"},{"note_desc":"a"},

Comment: That response barely contains any of the properties your JS code is using...?

Comment: @Ginie the json you just posted is not the same format as the image. We need to see it all, not just part of it. Also include you html

Comment: i am unable to share whole code becode it is too long by 147 words but what i want to say is my category is coming on change

Comment: function loadcategory(){
  $.ajax({ 
            url: 'ajax_task.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {'load_p_cat_data':'load_p_cat_data'},
            success:function(data){
             // alert(data);
           $('#category').html(data);
           
            }
          });
}
loadcategory();

Comment: $(document).on("change","#category",function(){ 
     var item_cat_id = $(this).val();
     var abc = this;
          $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url: 'ajax_task.php',
         data: {item_cat_id:item_cat_id,'load_p_item_data':'load_p_item_data'},
         success:function(data){
          
           $(abc).parents("tr").find("#item_name").html(data);
         }
       });
 });

Comment: <td>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                       
                                       <select class="form-control category"  style='width: 150px;' name="category[]" id="category"  value=""  required>
                                       </select>
                                       </div>
                    </td>

Comment: <td >
                                      <div class="form-group">
                               
                                      <select  style='width: 150px;' value="" class="form-control item_name" name="item_name[]" id='item_name'  required>
                                     
                                       </select>
                                </div>